# How to pass two edittext values to listview in another activity in android?

Tags: android

Hi I have two `EditText` values and want to pass them to customized `ListView` in another activity. Please help me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

To pass values from one Activity to another, use Intent with a Bundle. A Bundle is object containing a set of objects your are to set in a key/value store (I assume is backed by a HashMap). In your case, you want to pass two EditText values (Strings). So you are going to use a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) passed via [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to another activity:

```
    //In first Activity that isn't the ListView Activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourListActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("stringOne", editTextOne.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("stringTwo", editTextTwo.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);

    //Now in your List Activity's onCreate() method you can do the following
    Bundle extras;
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    }

    //Now, anywhere after in your List Activity you can access
    //the EditText strings from first Activity

    // (Somewhere later in your code, or just in your onCreate method)
    String first = extras.getString("stringOne");
    String second = extras.getString("stringTwo");
```

Comment: Thanq!! But how to retrieve the edit text values into the listview?? Like could you give the syntax for the listview adapter

Comment: In the ListView adapter you can pass a String[] or List<String> that has those two strings in them I guess, to the constructor. What is your plan to use the two EditText strings for? If it's for a header / footer, you can simply set those outside the adapter in your activity

Answer (score 0):

at first class

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    EditText editT1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editT1);
    EditText editT2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editT2);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(First_activity.this,Second_activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("text1", et1.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("text2", et2.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Image_URL", "your_image_url");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

then in second class

```
ListView List;
```

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_second); 
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         String text1 = intent.getStringExtra("text1");
         String text2 = intent.getStringExtra("text2");

```
    List=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);//your listview id
    ListAdapter ListAdapter=new ListAdapter(this,text1,text2);
    List.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

}
```

Now create your own listadapter

```
  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Activity context;
        String title[];
        String description[];

        public ListAdapter (Activity context, String[] title, String[] description) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return title.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtViewTitle;
            TextView txtViewDescription;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dital_list_view, null);//your listview layout
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);//forst textview id
                holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
                convertView.setTag(holder);//second text view id
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
            holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

now create listview layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    -<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/titleText"/>

    <TextView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/descriptionText" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

i hope it be helpful